# UL even margin with different heights

Tags: html, css

I have an UL which contains multiple photos for a portfolio which in only some of the photos needs a simple line of text that contains the name of the model.

I wrote it like this:

```
<ul> 
<li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt="image" /><p>Model Name</p></li>
<li><img src="img/2.jpg" alt="image" /></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is that the photo which has the text will be position higher up (like it has a different margin from the top) here's a screen of what I'm trying to describe:

[image]

What I want is that all the photos have the same space above them.

The full code can be seen here: http://prv.sampettersson.com

Comment: How about inserting `<p>&nbsp;</p>` for models/photos without a name?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: @UweKeim That works, although that seems quite a weird way to fix it. Shouldn't there be another way to fix this?

Comment: @Cherniv http://jsfiddle.net/xTump/

Comment: @SamPettersson great , so  *insertusernamehere* gives you exact answer

Comment: I think visible horizontal scroll is not a good idea, try to solve it.

Comment: @hallaji What do you mean?

Comment: @SamPettersson I mean that horizontal scroll should not be visible in websites. It's bad. You can hide it. Yo have a button that user can scroll photos with it.

Comment: @hallaji It isn't bad, most photographer's use this layout. And i do want the user to be able to scroll by him/herself the arrow/button is only there to hint the user of the horizontal layout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to use `vertical-align: top` on the `<li>`-elements. The default setting is `baseline` which leads to the result you see.

Comment: Here's also an article about it on CSS-tricks.com with some more details: [What is Vertical Align?](http://css-tricks.com/what-is-vertical-align/)